# github code review как убрать файл?

Tags: git, github

Мне отправили файл на code-review в guthub, и в одном из комитов есть измененный файл, который я не хочу принимать (содержит незначительные изменения которые не нужны), а все остальное устраивает и готов сделать merge c мастером.

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие действия должны быть? Могу ли я как-то убрать этот файл (прямо из панели code-review) или как-то еще ?
Или не должен принять code-review и отправить на переделку ? Как обычно поступают ?
И также, если я отправлю на переделку, то какие действия должен предпринять разработчик, которому отправлю ? Т.е. как ему нужно убрать этот файл из комита  ?

Comment: никто не знает?(

Answer (score 0):

Можно запросить изменения у разработчика. В пулл рекевесте нажимаете `Review changes` и выбираете `Request changes`. Разработчик или кидает ещё один коммит с нужными изменениями, или откатывает назад у себя все коммиты локально, коммитит только нужные изменения без того файла и форс-пушит всё заново.

Можно самому нажать `Edit` на нужном файле (дропдаун `...` в верхнем правом углу), внести нужные изменения и закоммитить их.